# Trouble In pass values from adapter to fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm passing value from adapter to fragment class,

Here adapter class,

```
 rbFolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(selected != null)
                {
                    selected.setChecked(false);
                    String meee =  data.get(position).getTypeId();
                    System.out.println("*******so*inside********"+meee);

                }

                rbFolder.setChecked(true);
               String so =  data.get(position).getTypeId();
                System.out.println("*******so*********"+so);
                selected = rbFolder;
                System.out.println("********selected*******"+selected);
                Fragment homepage = new Fragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentManager =((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("name", so); //key and value
                System.out.println("*****venki***meee*******"+so);

                homepage.setArguments(bundle);
              //  fragmentManager.replace(R.id.content_frame, homepage);
                fragmentManager.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentManager.commit();
            }
        });
```

In this, putstring working well but in my fragemt class i didnt receive values. I'm trouble in this place.
Here Fragmnet class,

```
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootview != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootview.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootview);
    }
    try {

        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
    /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }
```

Here I get values from adapter but this is not working,

```
   Bundle bundle = ((Activity)context).getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        String strtext=getArguments().getString("name");
        System.out.println("*******strtext*********"+strtext);

    }

    return rootview;
}
```

Comment: where is the adapter in activity or fragment?

Comment: I don't see if you have added or replaced homepage fragment anywhere.

Comment: Also move `homepage.setArguments(bundle);` before calling add/replace fragment

Comment: you can use also value form activity from fragment cats your activity context from fragment and get direct data from the activity

Answer (score 1):

First of All you have to call your **HomeFragment**() instead of **fragment** like that

```
Fragment homepage = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager =((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", so); //key and value
            homepage.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentManager.replace(R.id.content_frame, homepage);
            fragmentManager.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentManager.commit();
```

When you want to get value inside **home fragment** then

```
    if( getArguments() != null)
      String strtext = getArguments().getString("name");
```

Comment: Thank you Its working fine. Im using radio button in listview. I choose radio button in listview. I get value from adapter to fragment. but after i receive value . fragment class get refresh fragment class . so radio button goes to unchecked. how to solve this problem.

Comment: I chcked radio button and get value then i pass the value to fragment class. after received the values in fragment class. the page refresh so my radio button goes to unchecked state.How to display checked radio button

Comment: @Ana you can check in this http://www.androhub.com/android-listview-radiobutton/  & http://abhiandroid.com/ui/radiobutton-inside-listview.htmlmight be helpful

Answer (score 1):

- > **follow steps one by one,  copy Context context;
  >       List rowItems;
  >       onItemClickListner onItemClickListner; and pest into your adapter**
  >    **then copy two constructor methods and then pest on item click method to pass data to fragment.**
  >
  > in your fragment class set adapter item on click listener code in this way...

```html
madapter.setOnClickListener(new MyListAdapterTemp.onItemClickListner() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(String str) {
                 
             }
         });
```

```html
        Context context;
        List<String> rowItems;
        onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

  
        public MyListAdapterTemp(Context context, List<String> items) {
            this.context = context;
            this.rowItems = items;

        }

        public void setOnClickListener(onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
            this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;

        }

 
    holder.txtDesc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onItemClickListner.onClick(rowItems.get(position).toString().trim().toUpperCase());
                          
                }
            });
```

- > this method works fine on my app and for activity to fragment , fragment to activity we can pass data using interface but not this
  >   way this is best and proper way to perform this type of operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment homepage = new Fragment();
```

this is supposed to be your `Fragment` class name -

```
Fragment homepage = new MyFragment();
```

And Your Fragment be like -

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
         Bundle b = getArguments(); //To get extras from Fragment
    }
}
```

Other than that,

```
Bundle bundle = ((Activity)context).getIntent().getExtras();
```

This is used for an `Activity`. For `Fragment` you have to use `getArguments()`